# Как сделать вывод JSON всего контента без категорий

Tags: java, json

Как я могу сделать вывод JSON всего контента без под категорий что бы затем его можно было получить в java.
Я сейчас вывожу категория > меню категории .
А я хочу вывести всё меню без категорий которая будет отображаться в другой активности на java.
Помогите кто знает как это сделать.
**Вот мой вывод категория >меню категории на JSON.**

```
if(isset($_GET['accesskey']) && isset($_GET['category_id'])) {
    $access_key_received = $_GET['accesskey'];
    $category_ID = $_GET['category_id'];

    if(isset($_GET['keyword'])){
        $keyword = $_GET['keyword'];
    }else{
        $keyword = "";
    }

    if($access_key_received == $access_key){
        if($keyword == ""){
            // find menu by category id in menu table
            $sql_query = "SELECT Menu_ID, Menu_name, Price, Menu_image 
                FROM tbl_menu2 
                WHERE Category_ID = ".$category_ID." 
                ORDER BY Menu_ID DESC";
        }else{
            // find menu by category id and keyword in menu table
            $sql_query = "SELECT Menu_ID, Menu_name, Price, Menu_image 
                FROM tbl_menu2 
                WHERE Menu_name LIKE '%".$keyword."%' AND Category_ID = ".$category_ID." 
                ORDER BY Menu_ID DESC";
        }

        $result = $connect->query($sql_query) or die("Error : ".mysql_error());

        $menus = array();
        while($menu = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $menus[] = array('Menu'=>$menu);
        }

        // create json output
        $output = json_encode(array('data' => $menus));
    }else{
        die('accesskey is incorrect.');
    }
} else {
    die('accesskey and category id are required.');
}

//Output the output.
echo $output;
```

**А это мой java**

```
    Menu4API = Config2.ADMIN2_PANEL_URL+"/api/get-menu-data-by-category-id.php"+"?accesskey="+Config2.AccessKey+"&category_id=";  
Intent iGet = getIntent();
        Category_ID = iGet.getLongExtra("category_id",0);
        Category_name = iGet.getStringExtra("category_name");
        Menu4API += Category_ID; 
listMenu3.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // go to menu detail page
                Intent iDetail = new Intent(ActivityMenuList4.this, ActivityMenuDetail4.class);
                iDetail.putExtra("menu_id", Menu_ID.get(position));
                startActivity(iDetail);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);
            }
        });  
public void parseJSONData(){

        clearData();

        try {
            // request data from menu API
            URL url = new URL(Menu4API);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(20000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(20000);
            connection.connect();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            String str = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null){
                str += line;
            }

            // parse json data and store into arraylist variables
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
            JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data"); // this is the "items: [ ] part

            for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = data.getJSONObject(i);

                JSONObject menu = object.getJSONObject("Menu");

                Menu_ID.add(Long.parseLong(menu.getString("Menu_ID")));
                Menu_name.add(menu.getString("Menu_name"));
                Menu_price.add(Double.valueOf(formatData.format(menu.getDouble("Price"))));
                Menu_image.add(menu.getString("Menu_image"));

            }


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Я разобрался с этой задачей сам.
Вот таким способом.

```
if($access_key_received == $access_key){
        if($keyword == ""){
            // find menu by category id in menu table
            $sql_query = "SELECT Menu_ID, Menu_name, Price, Menu_image 
                FROM tbl_menu2 m, tbl_category2 c
                WHERE m.Category_ID = c.Category_ID  
                ORDER BY m.Menu_ID DESC";
        }else{
            // find menu by category id and keyword in menu table
        $sql_query ="SELECT Menu_ID, Menu_name, Price, Menu_image   
                FROM tbl_menu2 m, tbl_category2 c
                WHERE m.Category_ID = c.Category_ID AND Menu_name LIKE ? 
                ORDER BY m.Menu_ID DESC";
        }
```